# Upgraded WLAN; no internet

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, dell

I have Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit on a Dell XPS 13. I recently upgraded my WLAN from a broadcom to an intel 7265. On Ubuntu LIVE USB, the WiFi works when I connect to my wireless router; but on my actual Ubuntu installation the WiFi doesn't work. I checked the results of `lspci` on my installation and Linux successfully detects the new device. Presumably it just hasn't installed the drivers for it. There are no options for the intel 7265 driver under 'Additional Drivers', so where do I go to install the intel 7265 WiFi driver? I'm currently tethering my phone's WiFi to this laptop.

NOTE: Bluetooth works out of the box on the intel 7265, so it's not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by downloading the drivers off:

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html

Then copying the *.ucode files to `/lib/firmware`.